# Mostrar filas de la tabla con un clic (toggle)

Tags: php, html

Tengo una tabla HTML, donde si hace clic en "`<? Php echo $ row [" title "]; ?>` ", Para cada fila, se mostrará el ejercicio correspondiente a ese título (con los botones de radio como se puede ver en el código).

Esto funciona bien, muestra el ejercicio correctamente, pero me gustaría mostrar el ejercicio bajo su ‘Título’ correspondiente en otra fila de la tabla de una sola columna pero que ocupa el mismo ancho que la línea superior que tiene tres columnas. Por el momento, solo el ejercicio se muestra en la misma columna que `<? Php echo $ row ["title"]; ?>`.

Aquí hay un ejemplo que representa más o menos lo que quiero hacer:
http://jsfiddle.net/kr967kd6/1/

Podríais ayudarme con este problema?
Aquí está parte de mi código:

```
<tr>
            <td><?php echo $num_ex; ?></td>

            <!---Toggle Exercise-->
            <td><a  onclick="myFunction(<?php echo $row["exercise_id"] ?>)" role="button" class="btn" target="_blank" ><?php echo $row["title"]; ?></a>
                <!---Start Toggle--->
                <div id="toggle<?php echo $row["exercise_id"] ?>"  style="display:none">

                    <div id="centered_B" class="header">

                        <?php
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM exercises WHERE exercise_id='".$row["exercise_id"]."'";
                        $result_ej = $conn->query($sql); /*Check connection*/
                        $row_ej = $result_ej->fetch_assoc();
                        ?>

                        <p><?php echo $row["exercise_id"] . ". " . $row["text"]?></p>

                        <!--- Radio Button --->
                            <?php
                            if ($row["type"] == 0) {
                                $ansarray = explode("\n", $row["image_path"]);
                                $randomans = [];
                                for($i=0; $i<count($ansarray); $i++) {
                                    $a = array($i+1, $ansarray[$i]);
                                    array_push($randomans, $a);
                                }
                                shuffle($randomans);
                                for($i=0; $i<count($randomans); $i++) {
                                    echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"choice".$row["exercise_id"]."\" value= \"".$randomans[$i][0]."\"  />".$randomans[$i][1]."<br>";
                                    echo "</div>";
                                }

                                echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"choicetext".$row["exercise_id"]."\" value='multi' style=\"display:none;\">";

                            } else {
                                ?>
                                <input type="radio" name="choice<?php echo $row["exercise_id"] ?>" value= "0" checked="checked" style="display:none;" />

                                <?php
}
                            ?>
                    </div><!--- end of centered_B div --->

                </div></td>

            <td><?php echo $row["difficulty"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
```

Aquí está mi script:

```
<script>
    function myFunction(ejer_id) {
        var x = document.getElementById("toggle" + ejer_id);
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Vale ha conseguido hacer lo que quería. Pero ahora me sale como una especia de línea entre las filas de la tabla. ¿Sabéis por qué me pasa?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muestro mi código nuevo:

```
<tr>
            <td><?php echo $num_ex; ?></td> <!---Numero del ejercicio de manera ascendente-->
            <!---Click Toggle Exercise-->
            <td><a  onclick="myFunction(<?php echo $row["exercise_id"] ?>)" role="button" class="btn" target="_blank" ><?php echo $row["title"]; ?></a>
                </td>
            <td><?php echo $row["difficulty"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
<!--- Toggle --->
<tr id="toggle<?php echo $row["exercise_id"] ?>"  style="display:none">
<td colspan="3">
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM exercises WHERE exercise_id='".$row["exercise_id"]."'";
            $result_ej = $conn->query($sql); /*Check connection*/
            $row_ej = $result_ej->fetch_assoc();
            ?>

            <p><?php echo $row["exercise_id"] . ". " . $row["text"]?></p>
            <br>

            <!--- Radio Button --->

            <?php
            if ($row["type"] == 0) {

                $ansarray = explode("\n", $row["image_path"]);
                $randomans = [];
                for($i=0; $i<count($ansarray); $i++) {
                    $a = array($i+1, $ansarray[$i]);
                    array_push($randomans, $a);
                }
                shuffle($randomans);
                for($i=0; $i<count($randomans); $i++) {
                    echo "<div style=\"text-align:left; display:flex;\">";
                    echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"choice".$row["exercise_id"]."\" value= \"".$randomans[$i][0]."\"  />".$randomans[$i][1]."<br>";
                    echo "</div>";
                }

                echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"choicetext".$row["exercise_id"]."\" value='multi' style=\"display:none;\">";

            } else {
                ?>
                <input type="radio" name="choice<?php echo $row["exercise_id"] ?>" value= "0" checked="checked" style="display:none;" />

                <?php
            }
            ?>

 </td>
 </tr><!---Finish Toggle --->
```

Comment: Hice una actualización a mi respuesta. Revisa si funciona para lo que requieres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograrlo puedes usar el atributo `colspan="5"`. Te dejo una muestra con el código que pusiste en `JSFiddle`:

```js
$("#data tr td").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parent().next("tr").toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
table { 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  overflow: hidden; 
} 
input[type=checkbox] { 
  display: none; 
} 
.toggle{
  display:none;
}

/*input[type=checkbox]:checked table ~ tr.toggle { 
  display: table-row; 
  width: calc(100% - 20px); 
} */

.toggle.active {
  display: table-row; 
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}

label { 
  cursor: pointer; 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  width: 1000px; 
  z-index: 2; 
} 
 th, td { border: solid 1px #000; text-align: left; padding: 5px; position: relative; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="child1" type="checkbox">
<input id="child2" type="checkbox">
<table class="test-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Division</th>
                <th>Hire Date</th>
             </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="data">
            <tr>
                <td><label for="child1"></label>Open</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr class="toggle">
                <td colspan="5">data</td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td><label for="child2"></label>Open</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr class="toggle">
                <td colspan="5">data</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Actualización:**

Lo último que agregaste en tu pregunta se da porque estás dibujando la fila siempre, así:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="3">
    <div id="toggle<?php echo $row["exercise_id"] ?>"  style="display:none">
```

Si te fijas en el ejemplo, se utiliza el atributo `class` y se hace directamente en el `tr`, así:

```
<tr class="toggle">
    <td colspan="5">data</td>
</tr>
```

Por lo tanto, en tu código debe quedar algo así:

```
<tr id="toggle<?php echo $row["exercise_id"] ?>" style="display:none">
  <td colspan="3">
    <div id="centered_B" class="header">
```

Comment: Siii justo eso necesito gracias!! pero como mi script es diferente al del ejemplo de JSFiddle, como lo puedo hacer? Lo he intentado ponerlo más o menos parecido pero deja de funcionar el 'Toggle'

Comment: DjCrazy acabo de editar el código como me dices. Se ha arreglado el problema de la fila en blanco o 'padding', pero ahora el colspan=3 no lo coge bien. Cuando hago click en el 'Título' me aparece el ejercicio debajo en una columna. No coge las 3 columnas.

Comment: No alcanzo a determinar la razón por la que no funciona `colspan="3"`... Intenta usar el atributo `class="toggle"` en lugar de `id="toggle<?php echo $row["exercise_id"] ?>"` y tu `script` trata de adaptarlo al ejemplo que te dejé.

Comment: De acuerdo gracias por tu ayuda!!